# pgrep returning true in makefile but not in shell

Tags: bash, makefile, process, grep

How come when I use `pgrep` in a Makefile it finds a process ID but doesn't when run in a shell? For example, say I have this makefile

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

tst:
    if pgrep -f askdfkasdfj ; then     \
      kill $$(pgrep -f askdfkasdfj);   \
    fi
```

When I run `make tst` it finds a process and goes into the `if` body even though there is no process with the name "askdfkasdfj". I was trying to replace `ps aux | grep ...`, which works fine in this instance, with `pgrep` and ran into this problem.

Comment: FYI, if you have `pgrep`, you probably also have `pkill`.

Comment: yes, good point :)

Comment: Are you doing something like `make askdfkasdfj`? Then `pgrep` will find the `make` command.

Comment: no, I am just running `make tst`. The process ID that is put on stdout doesnt seem to exist after make exits either

Comment: @Barmar what you said makes me think that make starts a process with the whole command as part of its name though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's finding the command coming from the makefile itself. `make` is executing something like:

```
/bin/bash -c 'if pgrep -f askdfkasdfj ; then kill $$(pgrep -f askdfkasdfj); fi'
```

This contains `askdfkasdfj` in the `-c` argument, so it matches.

But I'm not sure why this didn't happen as well when you used `ps aux | grep`.

Comment: What do you see if you use `pgrep -l -f ...`. Then you should see the whole command line.

Comment: I  was using `pgrep -a`. Do you mean use that in the `if` clause? I'm not sure this explains it since even when the name is convoluted as a regex it still returns true

Comment: Yes, in the `if` clause. What do you see?

Comment: yes you are right. Using a regex actually does work. I had commented out the kill line, but even commented lines get put into the name of the process!